# Change width of image and adjust height automatically with Quick Action

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

If you have an image file, you can do the following:

- Open the file in Apples Preview app
- Go to: Tools>Adjust size…
- Check "Scale proportionally"
- Change the value in "Width:", in my case to 100 pixels

This looks like this:

[image: Adjust size in Apples Preview app]

This will change the width of the image and automatically adjust the height, without cutting the image.

I'd like to create a Quick Action, which does that for me: change the width to 100 px and adjust the height automatically.

Is it possible, to do that with Automators Quick Action editor?

Comment: To answer the question that you’ve actually asked: “Is it possible, to do that with Automators Quick Action editor?” – yes. If you dig around in Automator for ‘resize’, it should hopefully be reasonably clear from that point.

Comment: @user16966757 This isn't what I'm looking for since this cuts the image (or sometimes adds some space) instead of adjusting the height.

Comment: Read my answer (with comments under the script) to see how to set the Automator service properly.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Thanks, I did, but I get the error: `Cannot read item 1 of {}`

Comment: You should select some image file(s) in the Finder before running the service

Comment: @RobertKniazidis I know. There's an image file (screenshot) on my desktop: Right click>Quick actions>"Set width to 100 px". I get a popup: `Cannot read „item 1 of {}“`

Comment: Your input is empty. I don't know what you does.

Comment: @David Ah yes, I understand what you're saying about the built-in Automator scale function. Have added an answer on how I'd approach this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`sips`** is a Mac-specific, Apple-written command-line program with some basic image processing actions. The `--resampleWidth` option does what you need. (Can get more details on what `sips` can do via `man sips` within Terminal.)

This `sips` command would resize an image to the size you want:

```
sips --resampleWidth 100 path/to/image.png
```

To use it within Automator, we can wrap that in this code:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    sips --resampleWidth 100 "$f"
done
```

This can then be triggered with the *Run Shell Script* Automator action:

[image: automator configuration]

### Notes/caveats

1. If the original image is *smaller* than 100px wide, this command
   will scale it to be **larger than it originally was**.
2. Also, as pointed out in the comments, using `sips` **may result in
   some metadata which is in the original image not being present in
   the scaled copy**.

### Rotation problems?

In the comments it's suggested that `sips` doesn't work correctly with images rotated 90°(/270°). I tested this and it appeared to work as expected, with the width of the output image being 100 in both cases.

[image: 90 degree rotation test]

Images tested were rotated using Preview. It's my understanding that there are two types of image rotation:

1. The image is re-saved with all the pixels in the new, rotated positions.
2. The pixel data is unchanged, and data is added to the image to say 'read in all the pixel data, then before you display it, translate everything (e.g.) 90°'.

The second approach avoids resaving, which may be problematic with lossy formats, as multiple rotations would lose data each time, i.e., four rotations would *not* end up with the original data again. I vaguely remember some problems using `sips` with this kind kind of image rotation, but it looks to me that it's potentially now been fixed. I'm using build 294 of `sips` [as displayed by typing `sips -v` into Terminal] with Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7).

For certainty I'd suggest testing with a lossy format such as JPEG to see if Preview/sips behave differently with rotations.

Comment: This OP question was forgotten by everyone until I answered it. "Solutions", moreover, unfinished ones, poured in at once. Also, the OP complained in another post that **sips** erases some metadata. You at least make it so that your script scales correctly no matter if the width or height is greater. Or don't interfere where your knowledge is limited.

Comment: Also, sips incorrectly detects the height and width if the image is rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Coincidental timing - just happened to show up in the top of my list today, and I'd solved a similar problem myself (I thought!) using built-in Automator actions. Your reminder that the built-in resize was on longest-dimension rather than specifically height (which OP pointed out at same time) made me stop using my phone and go look at the action I'd written to do the near-identical job years ago. Good point about the metadata - will add that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis I tested this with an image I rotated 90° and it looked OK to me.

Comment: It depends on what is considered the width of the rotated image. But since the OP has decided that your script is what he wants, I want to end there.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Agreed – added example for clarity. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set targetWidth to 100
    repeat with anAlias in (get contents of input)
        set hfsPath to anAlias as text
        try
            tell application "Image Events"
                launch
                set anImage to open (file hfsPath)
                set {w, h} to dimensions of anImage
                if w > h then
                    scale anImage to size targetWidth
                else
                    scale anImage to size (round (targetWidth * h / w) rounding up)
                end if
                save anImage with icon
                close anImage
            end tell
        on error error_message
            display dialog error_message
        end try
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

1. Open Automator
2. Select creating Quick Action
3. Set "workflow receives image files in Finder.app"
4. Add Run AppleScript action with content above.
5. Save (this service)

Comment: @RobertKniazidis I get: `„Cannot read item 1 of {}“`

Comment: I haven't tested, but maybe the embedded Automator action scales by biggest size instead of scaling by width.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis - yep, you're right, it does

Comment: Problem here is likely not due to the inputs being wrong, but no `dimensions` (or anything else) being accessible by Image Events, due to Image Events not having been granted Full Disk Access permission. This affects Catalina 10.15, and possibly later OS versions. Issue is described [in the Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124420), with fix at the bottom of the article, or skip [straight to the fix](https://darjeelingsteve.com/articles/Fixing-%22Image-Events%22-AppleScripts-Broken-in-macOS-10.15-Catalina.html). This solution works for me after granting permission.